# use systemjs in a basic vanilla js page

Tags: javascript, systemjs, syncfusion

I'm trying to use a chart component from Syncfusion in a simple application I'm developing.

It's pure JS, no Angular, no React, no TypeScript. I've not even used NPM

My problem is that I'm not able to import the necessary files to make the chart component works!

Following the documentation founded here
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/chart/es5-getting-started/

I've added a systemjs.config.js in my folder /_assets/systemjs.config.js and I've configured this way:

```
System.config({
    paths: {
        'syncfusion:': './_assets/vendors/Syncfusion/@syncfusion',
    },
    map: {
        app: 'app',

        //Syncfusion packages mapping
        "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "syncfusion:ej2-base/dist/ej2-base.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-data": "syncfusion:ej2-data/dist/ej2-data.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-charts": "syncfusion:ej2-charts/dist/ej2-charts.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-popups": "syncfusion:ej2-popups/dist/ej2-popups.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-buttons": "syncfusion:ej2-buttons/dist/ej2-buttons.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-pdf-export": "syncfusion:ej2-pdf-export/dist/ej2-pdf-export.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-file-utils": "syncfusion:ej2-file-utils/dist/ej2-file-utils.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-compression": "syncfusion:ej2-compression/dist/ej2-compression.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-navigations": "syncfusion:ej2-navigations/dist/ej2-navigations.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-calendars": "syncfusion:ej2-calendars/dist/ej2-calendars.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-lists": "syncfusion:ej2-lists/dist/ej2-lists.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-inputs": "syncfusion:ej2-inputs/dist/ej2-inputs.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-svg-base": "syncfusion:ej2-svg-base/dist/ej2-svg-base.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons": "syncfusion:ej2-splitbuttons/dist/ej2-splitbuttons.umd.min.js"
        ,
    },
    packages: {
        'app': { main: 'app', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
});
```

It talks about "app" but I don't have an *app* variable... I'm not using Angular neither React.

In the folder /_assets/vendors/Syncfusion/ I've inserted all the scripts files of Syncfusion:
[image]

Then in my HTML page I've added:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.38/system.js"></script>
<script src="/_assets/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

but when I run the page from the local dev web server I get:

Test:94 Uncaught ReferenceError: ej is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have analyzed your query. If you want to load only chart scripts instead of loading entire scripts. You can refer the charts and its dependency scripts alone.

Please find the below code snippet to achieve this requirement,

```
<head>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/dist/global/ej2-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-data/dist/global/ej2-data.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-svg-base/dist/global/ej2-svg-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-charts/dist/global/ej2-charts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
var chart = new ej.charts.Chart({
  // Other customization
});
chart.appendTo('#container');
</script>
</body>
```

Sample for your reference can be found from below link,
chart sample

Kindly revert us, if you have any concerns.

Regards,
Baby.

Comment: That's perfect and where can I find the list of dependencies for each ej2 control?

Answer (score 2):

We have analyzed your query. And we have prepared a sample based on your requirement. To render EJ2 charts, you need to just refer the following scripts. There is no need to config the system.cofig as like the configuration you have done. We have already change the documentation from our side. It will be refreshed in the month of June.

Please find the below code snippet to achieve this requirement,

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="line-container" align="center"></div>  
 <script>
var chart = new ej.charts.Chart({
  //Initializing 
});
chart.appendTo('#line-container');
  </script>
</body>
```

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/3ugmn8?file=index.html

Kindly revert us, if you have any concerns.

Regards,

Baby.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to load the entire package to use only a small portion of it.